# Area under a curve, failing to use Nintegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm calculating an integral and although Mathematica gives an answer it cannot possible be a correct one. It is the area of these two curves, the result says the integral is the same and it is too small for what the graph shows, it should be of the order of 0.9 for the blue one EP0 and 0.8 for the yellow one EP1, not 0.5 for sure. Any help would be very highly appreciated, I'm not sure which method I'm using incorrectly :(
[image]

The code to replicate all this is a bit long, here it is:

```
           Off[InterpolatingFunction::dmval]

    Hg1[gHat_, t0_, u0_, \[Epsilon]_, x0_] := 
      Module[{x = x0, u = u0, t = t0},
       PDEC := - 2 HC[
           p] (γB1[-p + u]/sD^2 - ( 
            x (γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u]) )/sD^2) + ( (
          x (x - 1))/(2 sD^2)) + 
         2 HC[p]^2 ((γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u])^2/
            sD^2 + (ϕ^2 (γA1[-p + u])^2)/sS^2) - 
         Derivative[1][HC][p];
       solC = NDSolve[{PDEC == 0, HC[0] == 0}, HC, {p, 0, (u - t) + 0.1}];
       PDEB :=  
        HB[p] ( (( x (γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u]) )/
              sD^2 - γB1[-p + u]/sD^2) + 
            2 (HC[p] /. 
               solC) ((γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u])^2/
               sD^2 + (ϕ^2 (γA1[-p + u])^2)/sS^2)) + 
         2 (HC[p] /. solC) (γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u] + 
            p (( γA1[-p + 
                  u] (γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u]) )/
               sD^2 - (ϕ^2 (γA1[-p + u])^2)/sS^2)) + 
         x (1 + (p γA1[-p + u])/sD^2) - Derivative[1][HB][p];
       solB = NDSolve[{PDEB == 0, HB[0] == 0}, HB, {p, 0, (u - t) + 0.1}];
       PDEA1 :=  (HC[p] /. 
            solC) ((γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u])^2/
            sD^2 + (ϕ^2 (γA1[-p + u])^2)/sS^2) - 
         Derivative[1][HA1][p];
       solA1 = 
        NDSolve[{PDEA1 == 0, HA1[0] == 0}, HA1, {p, 0, (u - t) + 0.1}];
       PDEA2 :=  (HB[p] /. 
            solB) (1/
             2 ((γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u])^2/
               sD^2 + (ϕ^2 (γA1[-p + u])^2)/
               sS^2) + γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u] + 
            p (( γA1[-p + 
                  u] (γB1[-p + u] - γA1[-p + u]) )/
               sD^2 - (ϕ^2 (γA1[-p + u])^2)/sS^2)) - 
         Derivative[1][HA2][p];
       solA2 = 
        NDSolve[{PDEA2 == 0, HA2[0] == 0}, HA2, {p, 0, (u - t) + 0.1}];
       Exp[Evaluate[HC[u - t] /. solC] gHat^2 + 
         gHat \[Epsilon] Evaluate[
           HB[u - t] /. solB] + \[Epsilon]^2 Evaluate[
           HA2[u - t] /. solA2] + Evaluate[HA1[u - t] /. solA1]]];
σA = 0.2;
σX = 0.4;
fBar = 0.015;
sD = 0.13;
sS = 0.2;
ρ := 
  0.2;                          (* Subjective discount rate  *)
α := -2;                                 (* Relative Risk \
aversion is := 1 - α  *)
lev = 1;                                 (* Leverage*)                \

ϕ = 95/100;
η = 1;
fA = fBar;
gA = (σX^2 (σX^2 (1 - ϕ) + \
σA^2))/(σX^2 + σA^2);
 gB = (σX^2 σA^2)/(σX^2 + σA^2);
λA := 
  1/2;                         (* Lagrange multiplier for Agent A's \
budget constraint at date 0  *)
λB := 
  1/2;                         (* Lagrange multiplier for Agent B's \
budget constraint at date 0  *)
ω0 = ((1/λA)^((1/(
  1 - α)))) /((1/λA)^(1/(
   1 - α)) + ((η λB)/λA)^(1/(
   1 - α)));

γA1[t_] := γA1[t] = 1/(  
   t (1/sD^2 + ϕ^2/sS^2) + 1/gA);
γB1[t_] := γB1[t] = sD^2/ (t + sD^2/gB);

HF1[fA_, t_, u_, \[CurlyEpsilon]_] := 
  Exp[-(((t - 
       u) \[CurlyEpsilon] (sD^2 (2 fA + (-1 + \[CurlyEpsilon]) sD^2) \
sS^2 + gA (t (-1 + \[CurlyEpsilon]) ϕ^2 sD^4 + 2 fA t sS^2 + 
          sD^2 (2 fA t ϕ^2 + (-t + u \[CurlyEpsilon]) sS^2))))/(
    2 (sD^2 sS^2 + t gA (ϕ^2 sD^2 + sS^2))))];


EqPricej1[ω_, gHat_, fA_, t_, u_?NumericQ, j_] := 
  Exp[- ρ(u - t)] HF1[fA, t, 
    u, α] (ω)^(1 - α) Binomial[1 - α, 
    j] (1/ω - 1)^j Hg1[gHat, t, u, α, j/(1 - α)];
EP0[ω_, gHat_, fA_, t_, u_?NumericQ] := 
  Sum[EqPricej1[ω, gHat, fA, t, u, j], {j, 0, 1 - α}];
EP1[ω_, gHat_, fA_, t_, u_?NumericQ] := 
  Sum[EqPricej1[ω, gHat, fA, t, u, j], {j, 0, -α}];
```

Comment: Could you check your code? I am getting a different curve (Ep0[u=0]=0.7, EP1[u=0]=0.52) and integration results are `0.650417` and `0.487813`.

Comment: I just checked, thank you! I had copied EqPricej1 with an extra space that was messing up the calculation.

Comment: I mean, you should now be able to replicate mi problem :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Problem is the [`First`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html).

Plainly evaluated this makes this

```
[in]:= EP0[ω0, -3/100, fA, 0, x] // First

[out]:= 2^(1/3)/(1 + 2^(1/3))
```

Which is omega0. So it just extracts your first parameter.

You can fix this easily by adding a simple `[[1]]` after every `NDSolve` in your `Hg1`-Function to get rid of the Lists.

Your results are btw:

```
0.943237
0.85967
```

Answer (score 1):

Can also solve it by tacking a `First` onto the definition of EqPricej1` which in its original form returns a list of one element.

```
EqPricej1[ω_, gHat_, fA_, t_, u_?NumericQ, j_] := Exp[...........]//First;
```